# Config variable for API key returns undefined in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, environment-variables, dotenv

1. I am using dotenv npm package to hide sensitive data in my app. The config variables for backend and frontend/React are defined locally inside .env file. The app works fine locally.
2. I deployed my app to Heroku and added config variables manually to Heroku.
3. I have 4 variables, 3 for backend, 1 for React. While the VARs for backend works properly in Heroku, the VAR which I use in React to fetch data from external API returns undefined.
4. React var has a prefix REACT_APP_ and as I said above it works fine locally and I can fetch data from external API. The only problem I have is, it doesn't work in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing the requirement for `dotenv` module in front-end. Simply I removed the code below and deployed to Hereoku again.

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'client', '.env.development'), debug: true});
```